# Errors loading Blender Wavefront Model

Tags: java, parsing, jogl, wavefront

Hopefully someone can help me. I am trying to load a model I made in Blender into my JOGL program. I was able to manual models working and set up my window but there is something wrong with parsing the .obj wavefront file. No errors in my code that I can see, the ImportedModel class came from a textbook.

Here is the code:

```
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator;
import org.joml.Matrix4f;
import org.joml.Vector2f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.*;



public class WalkingTour extends JFrame implements GLEventListener, KeyListener {


private static final int windowWidth = 800, windowHeight = 600;
private static final String windowTitle = "Walking Tour";
private static final String vertexShaderFile = "src/walkingtour-vertex.glsl",
        fragmentShaderFile = "src/walkingtour-fragment.glsl";
private final GLCanvas glCanvas;
private int renderingProgram;
private final int[] vao = new int[1];
private final int[] vbo = new int[6];
private final FloatBuffer values = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(16);
private final Matrix4f pMat = new Matrix4f();  // perspective matrix
private final Matrix4f vMat = new Matrix4f();  // view matrix
private final Matrix4f mMat = new Matrix4f();  // model matrix
private final Matrix4f mvMat = new Matrix4f(); // model-view matrix
private int gTexture;
private ImportedModel myModel;
private int numObjVertices;

private boolean keyPressedForward = false,
        keyPressedBackward = false,
        keyPressedMoveRight = false,
        keyPressedMoveLeft = false,
        keyPressedTurnRight = false,
        keyPressedTurnLeft = false,
        keyPressedSpace = false,
        keyPressedControl = false,
        keyPressedShift = false;
private final ArrayList<Float> vertexValues = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> stVals = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> normalValues = new ArrayList<>();


private final ArrayList<Float> triangleVerts = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> textureCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
private final ArrayList<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();

private List<float[]> vertices = new ArrayList<float[]>();
private List<int[]> faces =new ArrayList<int[]>();



public WalkingTour() {
    setTitle(windowTitle);
    setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glCanvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.getMaxProgrammableCore(true)));
    glCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
    this.add(glCanvas);
    this.setVisible(true);
    Animator animator = new Animator(glCanvas);
    animator.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new WalkingTour();
}



@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {

    myModel = new ImportedModel("hwk5Model.obj");

    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

    numObjVertices = myModel.getNumVertices();
    Vector3f[ ] vertices = myModel.getVertices();
    Vector2f[ ] texCoords = myModel.getTexCoords();
    Vector3f[ ] normals = myModel.getNormals();
    float[ ] pvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];        // vertex positions
    float[ ] tvalues = new float[numObjVertices*2];        // texture coordinates
    float[ ] nvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];        // normal vectors

    for (int i=0; i<numObjVertices; i++)
    {   pvalues[i*3]   = (float) (vertices[i]).x();
        pvalues[i*3+1]     = (float) (vertices[i]).y();
        pvalues[i*3+2]  = (float) (vertices[i]).z();
        tvalues[i*2]    = (float) (texCoords[i]).x();
        tvalues[i*2+1]  = (float) (texCoords[i]).y();
        nvalues[i*3]    = (float) (normals[i]).x();
        nvalues[i*3+1]  = (float) (normals[i]).y();
        nvalues[i*3+2]  = (float) (normals[i]).z();
    }

    // VBO for vertex locations
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
    FloatBuffer vertBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(pvalues);
    gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// VBO for texture coordinates
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[3]);
    FloatBuffer texBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(tvalues);
    gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuf.limit()*4, texBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// VBO for normal vectors
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[4]);
    FloatBuffer norBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(nvalues);
    gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, norBuf.limit()*4,norBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    renderingProgram = Utils.createShaderProgram(vertexShaderFile, fragmentShaderFile);
    gTexture = Utils.loadTexture("groundTexture.jpeg");
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexture);
    

    float[] floor = {
            -2000.0f, -50.0f, -2000.0f, -2000.0f, -50.0f, 2000.0f, 2000.0f, -50.0f, 2000.0f,
            -2000.0f, -50.0f, -2000.0f, 2000.0f, -50.0f, -2000.0f, 2000.0f, -50.0f, 2000.0f,
    };

    gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);

    FloatBuffer corBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(floor);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, corBuf.limit() * 4L, corBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    float[] textureCoords = {
            0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
            0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0f
    };

    FloatBuffer textureBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(textureCoords);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
    gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureBuffer.limit() * 4L, textureBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
    this.removeKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable) {
    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

    gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

    int mvLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
    int pLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "p_matrix");

    float aspect = (float) glCanvas.getWidth() / (float) glCanvas.getHeight();
    pMat.identity().setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 5000.0f);
    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(pLoc, 1, false, pMat.get(values));

    vMat.translate(0f,0f,0f);

    mvMat.identity();
    mvMat.mul(vMat);
    mvMat.mul(mMat);

    gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvMat.get(values));
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gTexture);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myModel.getNumVertices());

    if (keyPressedForward) {
        vMat.translateLocal(0f, 0f, 0.1f);
    }
    if (keyPressedBackward) {
        vMat.translateLocal(0f,0f,-0.1f);
    }
    if (keyPressedMoveLeft) {
        vMat.translateLocal(0.1f,0f,0f);
    }
    if (keyPressedMoveRight) {
        vMat.translateLocal(-0.1f,0f,0f);
    }
    if (keyPressedTurnLeft) {
        vMat.rotateLocalY(-0.001f);
    }
    if (keyPressedTurnRight) {
        vMat.rotateLocalY(0.001f);
    }
    if (keyPressedSpace) {
        vMat.translateLocal(0f,-0.1f,0f);
    }
    if (keyPressedControl) {
        vMat.translateLocal(0f,0.1f,0f);
    }
    if (keyPressedForward && keyPressedShift){
        vMat.translateLocal(0f,0f,0.2f);
    }


}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //do nothing
}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        // Move camera forward
        keyPressedForward = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        // Move camera backward
        keyPressedBackward = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        // Move camera to the left
        keyPressedMoveLeft = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        // Move camera to the right
        keyPressedMoveRight = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_HOME || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
        // Turn camera to the left
        keyPressedTurnLeft = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
        // Turn camera to the right
        keyPressedTurnRight = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        // Move camera up
        keyPressedSpace = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
        // Move camera down
        keyPressedControl = true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
        //hold shift to "sprint"
        //can only sprint while forward buttons are pressed
        keyPressedShift = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            // Move camera forward
            keyPressedForward = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            // Move camera backward
            keyPressedBackward = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            // Move camera to the left
            keyPressedMoveLeft = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            // Move camera to the right
            keyPressedMoveRight = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_HOME || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
            // Turn camera to the left
            keyPressedTurnLeft = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            // Turn camera to the right
            keyPressedTurnRight = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            // Move camera up
            keyPressedSpace = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
            // Move Camera down
            keyPressedControl = false;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            //hold shift to "sprint"
            keyPressedShift = false;
        }
}
}

import org.joml.Vector2f;
import org.joml.Vector3f;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImportedModel {
private Vector3f[ ] vertices;
private Vector2f[ ] texCoords;
private Vector3f[] normals;
private int numVertices;

public ImportedModel(String filename) {
    ModelImporter modelImporter = new ModelImporter();

    try {
        modelImporter.parseOBJ(filename);   // uses modelImporter to get vertex information
        numVertices = modelImporter.getNumVertices();
        float[ ] verts = modelImporter.getVertices();
        float[ ] tcs = modelImporter.getTextureCoordinates();
        float[ ] norm = modelImporter.getNormals();

        this.vertices = new Vector3f[numVertices];
        this.texCoords = new Vector2f[numVertices];
        this.normals = new Vector3f[numVertices];

        for(int i=0; i<vertices.length; i++)
        { vertices[i] = new Vector3f();
            vertices[i].set(verts[i*3], verts[i*3+1], verts[i*3+2]);
            texCoords[i] = new Vector2f();
            texCoords[i].set(tcs[i*2], tcs[i*2+1]);
            this.normals[i] = new Vector3f();
            this.normals[i].set(norm[i*3], norm[i*3+1], norm[i*3+2]);
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    { e.printStackTrace();
    } }
public int getNumVertices() { return numVertices; } // accessors
public Vector3f[ ] getVertices() { return vertices; }
public Vector2f[ ] getTexCoords() { return texCoords; }
public Vector3f[ ] getNormals() { return normals; }

private static class ModelImporter
{ // values as read in from OBJ file
    private final ArrayList<Float> vertVals = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Float> stVals = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Float> normVals = new ArrayList<>();
    // values stored for later use as vertex attributes
    private final ArrayList<Float> triangleVerts = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Float> textureCoords = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<Float> normals = new ArrayList<>();
    public void parseOBJ(String filename) throws IOException
    {   InputStream input = Files.newInputStream(new File(filename).toPath());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {    if(line.startsWith("v"))        // vertex position ("v" case)
        {   for(String s : (line.substring(2)).split(" "))
        {   vertVals.add(Float.valueOf(s));    // extract the vertex position values
        } }
        else if(line.startsWith("vt"))        // texture coordinates ("vt" case)
        {   for(String s : (line.substring(3)).split(" "))
        {   stVals.add(Float.valueOf(s));     // extract the texture coordinate values
        } }
        else if(line.startsWith("vn"))        // vertex normals ("vn" case)
        {   for(String s : (line.substring(3)).split(" "))
        {   normVals.add(Float.valueOf(s));    // extract the normal vector values
        } }
        else if(line.startsWith("f"))         // triangle faces ("f" case)
        {   for(String s : (line.substring(2)).split(" "))
        {   String v = s.split("/")[0];        // extract triangle face references
            String vt = s.split("/")[1];
            String vn = s.split("/")[2];
            int vertRef = (Integer.parseInt(v)-1)*3;
            int tcRef = (Integer.parseInt(vt)-1)*2;
            int normRef = (Integer.parseInt(vn)-1)*3;
            triangleVerts.add(vertVals.get(vertRef));   // build array of vertices
            triangleVerts.add(vertVals.get(vertRef+1));
            triangleVerts.add(vertVals.get(vertRef+2));
            textureCoords.add(stVals.get(tcRef));   // build array of
            textureCoords.add(stVals.get(tcRef+1));     // texture coordinates.
            normals.add(normVals.get(normRef));     //… and normals
            normals.add(normVals.get(normRef+1));
            normals.add(normVals.get(normRef+2));
        } }}
        System.out.println(vertVals);
        System.out.println(stVals);
        System.out.println(normVals);
        input.close();
    }
    // accessors for retrieving the number of vertices, the vertices themselves,
    // and the corresponding texture coordinates and normals (only called once per model)
    public int getNumVertices() { return (triangleVerts.size()/3); }
    public float[ ] getVertices()
    {   float[ ] p = new float[triangleVerts.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < triangleVerts.size(); i++)
        { p[i] = triangleVerts.get(i);
        }
        return p;
    }

    public float[] getTextureCoordinates() {
        float[] p = new float[textureCoords.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < textureCoords.size(); i++) {
            p[i] = textureCoords.get(i);
        }
        return p;
}
    public float[] getNormals() {
        float[ ] p = new float[normals.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < normals.size(); i++)
        { p[i] = normals.get(i);
        }
        return p;
    }
    // similar accessors for texture coordinates and normal vectors go here
} }
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main-AWTAnimator#00" com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase$UncaughtAnimatorException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught NumberFormatException: empty String on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:92)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator$MainLoop.run(Animator.java:204)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught NumberFormatException: empty String on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.common.util.awt.AWTEDTExecutor.invoke(AWTEDTExecutor.java:58)
    at jogamp.opengl.awt.AWTThreadingPlugin.invokeOnOpenGLThread(AWTThreadingPlugin.java:103)
    at jogamp.opengl.ThreadingImpl.invokeOnOpenGLThread(ThreadingImpl.java:201)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invokeOnOpenGLThread(Threading.java:202)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:221)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:505)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught NumberFormatException: empty String on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.java:1438)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:416)
    at ImportedModel$ModelImporter.parseOBJ(ImportedModel.java:60)
    at ImportedModel.<init>(ImportedModel.java:18)
    at WalkingTour.init(WalkingTour.java:83)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:644)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:667)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$10.run(GLCanvas.java:1407)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1291)
    ... 16 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.java:1438)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:505)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:559)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:264)
    at sun.lwawt.LWRepaintArea.paintComponent(LWRepaintArea.java:59)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:240)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleJavaPaintEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1314)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1198)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4965)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkBufferObject(GL4bcImpl.java:40621)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkArrayVBOBound(GL4bcImpl.java:40653)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glVertexAttribPointer(GL4bcImpl.java:12429)
    at WalkingTour.display(WalkingTour.java:180)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1424)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    ... 30 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught GLException: array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method on thread AWT-EventQueue-0
    at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$12.run(GLCanvas.java:1438)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.Threading.invoke(Threading.java:223)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.display(GLCanvas.java:505)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.paint(GLCanvas.java:559)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.update(GLCanvas.java:866)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.updateComponent(RepaintArea.java:255)
    at sun.lwawt.LWRepaintArea.updateComponent(LWRepaintArea.java:47)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:232)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleJavaPaintEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1314)
    at sun.lwawt.LWComponentPeer.handleEvent(LWComponentPeer.java:1198)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4965)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: array vertex_buffer_object must be bound to call this method
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkBufferObject(GL4bcImpl.java:40621)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.checkArrayVBOBound(GL4bcImpl.java:40653)
    at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glVertexAttribPointer(GL4bcImpl.java:12429)
    at WalkingTour.display(WalkingTour.java:180)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:692)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas$11.run(GLCanvas.java:1424)
    at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
    ... 31 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Trying to parse a .obj model and use the extracted information to load my model into a JOGL program.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JOGL, your program expects a number and reads an empty string: "at ImportedModel$ModelImporter.parseOBJ(ImportedModel.java:60)".

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).